# Is there a way to paste multiple photo URLs as actual JPEGs into a Google Doc?

Tags: python, google-docs, photo

I have a text file with a number of URLs pointing to photos on the web. I can select a single URL, pop it into the address bar, and confirm I can see the photo.

What I'd like to do is move all those URLs into a Google Doc, but I want them to show up as the actual pictures, not the URLs. Is this possible via python or some Google Doc magic?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot propose a sample script because I cannot correctly imagine your current situation and your expected result. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, about `Is this possible via python`, I think that it's yes. By the way, what is `some Google Doc magic`?

Comment: The situation is this: I have a text document containing 100 urls that point to pictures. I'd like to be able to take those urls and get them into a Google doc, or Word doc, displaying the picture instead of the URL.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The situation is this: I have a text document containing 100 urls that point to pictures. I'd like to be able to take those urls and get them into a Google doc, or Word doc, displaying the picture instead of the URL.`, I think that it can be achieved with Google Document using Google Drive API and Google Docs API with python. By the way, what is `some Google Doc magic`?